# Have the live refresh mark handled suggested edits while in the Review page

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Sometimes I leave the [Review Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) page open for long minutes while going through the suggestions. If by the time I approve or reject a specific suggestion that suggestion was already handled (approved or rejected by two others) there are two cases:

1. If the handling was the same as my action it appears as though I was successful and the post vanish.
2. If the handling was conflicting my decision it show red alert to notify me.

I don't really mind this, but I do mind when I spend time to write custom reject reason  then find out only after I'm finished that it was for nothing as the suggestion was already rejected (or approved, it doesn't matter) before I even started.

Since we already have the live refresh live and kicking all around the place, I suggest to have it mark handled suggestion somehow - one way is to disable the action buttons for that suggestion or to have it behave the same like in other places something like this:

[image: mockup]

Comment: If I would be in reviewer position, I would dislike this behaviuor as well. Because on edits it works - if I have a question open, wait one hour and click edit, I would get current version with all edits from last hour.